# Location of windows command prompt command files

Tags: windows, command, bin

In Unix, the terminal commands are in /etc folder. Similarly, I'd like to know where the command files of Windows are located eg., `mkdir, cd,` etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: c:\windows\system32. also see this link: http://superuser.com/questions/229945/where-are-the-standard-windows-prompt-commands-files

Comment: @morpheus Thanks! Could you provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `where` to find where the executables are located.

Some as @sb9 said, are not separate exe's and they are built in. Using `where` you can find out if they have their own exe file or not.

```
where ftp
where at
where cd
```

In this case `cd` will error as it is built in.

Answer (score 4):

Some commands are located in windows\system32, and some others (like mkdir and cd) are built in internally into the shell cmd.exe, so you won't find them on the hard disk.